# Html5 time field always compare value with 24hour format on mobile

Tags: html, time

I am trying to add time picker using html5 default input field as

`<input type="time" name="stat-time" value="" max="03:15:00 PM" />`

Since i used `03:15:00 PM` for the max value, whereas; whenever user adds `4:00 Pm`, it generates error and show `Please enter a value less than or equal to 15:15:00 PM.`.

Although it is correct for showing error, but i want to display this error in **12 hour format**. like `Please enter a value less than equal to 4:15:00 PM`
In other words error should also be in same format which is taken by the input field.

Screenshot: [image]

Any Suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Note: This error can only reproduce on browser using mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

I come up with a trick, as far as, this issue is only on mobile devices, i used the php to add the `title` to modify the error message.

like `<input  name="start_time" type="time"   max="<?php echo $dt->format('H:i:s A'); ?>" value="" <?php echo $device != 'pc' ? 'title="Please enter a value less than equal to '.$dt->format('h:i:s A').'" : 'title="Enter time value"' '  ?>>`

Now it compares **24hour format** but will display the error message in **12 hour format**.

Though i still want to have a proper method to handle this issue in html5.